# Remove concrete __type information in JSON Response using JsonSerializer

Tags: servicestack, jsonserializer

How do you force the __type information from rendering in the deserialized JSON response?  I have no need to reserialize this data so I'd prefer to remove it.  ServiceStack seems to add this to the dictionary properties of my model.

This is using ServiceStack and ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer

Answer (score 23, accepted):

By default the **__type** is only emitted when it's required for deserialization, e.g. your DTO contains an interface, abstract class or late-bound object type, etc.

You can prevent it from ever being emitted with:

```
JsConfig.ExcludeTypeInfo = true;
```

Otherwise you can always emit it with:

```
JsConfig.IncludeTypeInfo = true;
```

Comment: Thanks!! Always a pleasure working with this framework mythz.

Comment: How and where should I set it? At `Service` implementation? At `AppHostBase.Configure()`?

Comment: Nevermind, I found it. Thanks! https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Configuration-options