# Dynamic object as response for ServiceStack request

Tags: servicestack

I run a test,  returning as response  a dynamic object (ExpandoObject).

It works, but  the JsonServiceClient cannot convert the object

and returns in  json format the data and  type descriptions.

Can we do something better ?

```
      public class DynamicAPIRequest : IReturn<object>
      { ...  }

      public object Post(DynamicAPIRequest request)
      {
        dynamic response = new ExpandoObject();  
        response.Name = "Donald Duck";         
        response.Nephews = new List<nephew>();
        response.Nephews.Add(new nephew { name = "Huey" } );
          ...
        return response;          
      }
```

In client side

```
         var nephews = client.Post<object>(new DynamicAPIRequest { uncle = "skroutz" });   
             /* returns
              {Name:Donald Duck,Nephews:[{__type:Test.Client.Model.nephew, 
               Test.Client.Model,name:Huey},{name:Dewey},{name:Louie}]}

              */
```

What other can I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get rid of the `__type` properties you will need set the configuration for serialization to exclude type info:

```
JsConfig.ExcludeTypeInfo = true;
```

From mythz in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731214/remove-concrete-type-information-in-json-response-using-jsonserializer):

> By default the __type is only emitted when it's required for deserialization, e.g. your DTO contains an interface, abstract class or late-bound object type, etc.

Comment: Mike thanks it works, excluding the type info. I still have another problem, how to derialize the json to  a var type  ( I tested  DynamicJson.Deserialize  in v4 -net.4   but without results)